# Mocking Hibernate's SessionFactory using EasyMock

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am trying to write a unit test for the following class:

```
@Transactional
public class EditorHelper {

private static SessionFactory sf;

static {        
    ClassPathResource hbr = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    File hbCfg = null;

    try {
        hbCfg = hbr.getFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (hbCfg != null) {
        sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(hbCfg).buildSessionFactory(); // <-- Stack trace points here
    }
}
public static void setSf(SessionFactory sf) {
    EditorHelper.sf = sf;
}
}
```

There are some other methods, but this setup code is what's relevant to my question.  In my unit test, I want to mock (using EasyMock) the `SessionFactory` object `sf`, as well as the `Session` and `Transaction` objects it will return:

```
public class EditorTest {

    private SessionFactory sf;
    private Session s;
    private Transaction tx;
    private Long id = 1L;
    private String idStr = id.toString();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        sf = EasyMock.createMock(SessionFactory.class);
        s = EasyMock.createMock(Session.class);
        tx = EasyMock.createMock(Transaction.class);

        EditorHelper.setSf(sf); // <-- Stack trace points here

        EasyMock.expect(sf.getCurrentSession()).andReturn(s);
        EasyMock.expect(s.beginTransaction()).andReturn(tx);
    }
// Tests go here
}
```

When I try to run this with JUnit, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:87)
    at com.mypkg.helper.EditorHelper.<clinit>(EditorHelper.java:38)
    at com.mypkg.model.EditorTest.setUp(EditorTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

There is no public `INSTANCE` variable on `sf` that I can see.  I'm new to EasyMock, so I think my question is: what should I tell my mock to return for `INSTANCE`, and how do I tell it to do that?  I don't know why the `SessionFactory` setup code is being called by `setSf()` at all, so that's another mystery.  The more general question is: how should I mock up a SessionFactory object anyway?

### Update

I figured out that catching the exception without doing anything will work just fine.  I have changed my `EditorHelper` class as follows:

```
@Transactional
public class EditorHelper {

private static SessionFactory sf;

static {    

...

    if (hbCfg != null) {
        try { // New try block lets the initializaiton fail
            sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(hbCfg).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
```

Once this static block completes, I can set the `SessionFactory` member to point to my mock object and everything works from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is being run because it is inside a static initialization block. Once your test refers to `EditorHelper,` the JVM will load the class and this initialization block will run and attempt to create a `SessionFactory` from the `AnnotationConfiguration` instance which is configured with the config XML file.

Which class are you trying to test? I note that the test is `EditorTest` and the class is `EditorHelper`. Is this intentional, and are you actually trying to test an `Editor` class?

Comment: Aha, I see! I assumed the static block would run at import (because that's how Python does it).  I'll try putting that initialization line in a try-catch.

Comment: You're pretty much right on about the test class. It's actually supposed to test several `*Editor` classes, which use some `EditorHelper` static methods to get database access. That's why I'm trying to mock a `SessionFactory` object rather than an `EditorHelper`.

Comment: If the `EditorHelper` is accessed statically, you won't be able to mock it and so there doesn't seem to be a good way to test the `Editor` classes. Can you inject the `SessionFactory` another way? Could you move the static initialization block into a static `initialize` method for use in production code and use `setSessionFactory` in testing?

Comment: I think what I'll probably do is put the `SesssionFactory` initialization into a really permissive `try` block so that it's free to fail, and then inject the mock `SessionFactory` object. I've gotten sidetracked away from this for a few days, but I'll update when I get back to it.  I expect that to work, though.

Comment: Yes, that worked as expected.  I will post the updated code.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!